# Shell Script to Move a File Into Another User's Directory?

Tags: shell, file, scripting, permissions

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 server.  On my server, I have a file in directory `/home/userA/dirA`:

```
userA@myUbuntu:~$ 
userA@myUbuntu:~$ pwd
/home/userA
userA@myUbuntu:~$ 
userA@myUbuntu:~$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 3 userA userA 4096 Feb 17 14:13 dirA
userA@myUbuntu:~$ 
userA@myUbuntu:~$ ls -l dirA/
total 7796
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userA userA  1234 Feb 17 14:05 theFile.txt
userA@myUbuntu:~$
```

Note the ownership here; user `userA` owns the file and the directory where the file resides.

I need a shell script that moves `theFile.txt` to another location, into a directory that is not owned by `userA`.  Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Attempting to move file..."
{
        sudo mv /home/userA/dirA/theFile.txt /home/userB/dirB/.
} || {
   echo "Failed to move file!"
}
```

...and the output:

```
userA@myUbuntu:~$ ./myScript.sh
Attempting to move file...
Failed to move file!
userA@myUbuntu:~$
```

As you can tell, the script runs as `userA`.  I don't want to run it as `root`.

So I'm assuming the script is failing because of the permissions; a script run as `userA` does not have permission to move a file into a directory owned by `userB`.  I've been trying all sorts of variations of the `sudo` command and others, but to no avail.  I've also tried goofy workarounds, like copying the file to `/tmp` (that works) and then doing a `chown` to change file ownership (that doesn't work).  But there's got to be a way to neatly do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new group, add both users into it and set the appropriate permissions. After that you will be able to move files between folders.

Comment: Thanks Zhelev!  Appreciate the help!  I've created a new group and added both users.  I've also done a "chgrp" on the script, the directory where the file sits, and the directory to where I want to move the file, so now they are all members of the new group.  But my script still fails.  Should that have done the trick, or am I missing something?  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! Try to run this command in the bash terminal and see the output(paste it here), run it with and without ```sudo```.

Comment: Thanks again Zhivko!  I implemented your suggestion, and now my script works.  If you write this up as a formal answer, I will credit you with the solution.  Thanks again for writing!